# Change ajax form action with input's formaction attribute

Tags: .net, ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I have used to have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <input type="submit" formaction="/home" />
}
```

And everything was brilliant but with Ajax form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm())
{
  <input type="submit" formaction="/home" />
}
```

submitted form action doesn't reflect formaction of input.
Where is the problem and how can i make ajax form work with different form actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, this functionality wasn't implemented in MVC3.
One of workaround - rewrite with jQuery rendered `data-ajax-url` attribute, it will appear when you specify `Url` property in `AjaxOptions` of `BeginForm` method.